# How to solve function with fractions?

Tags: calculus

$$f(x+h) - f(x) \over h$$ when $f(x) = \frac{1}{2x}$

This is what the book says to do:

[image: Inline page scan]

I don't understand the part after the red square. How does the h jump from the bottom to the middle like that? Was it an error by the author?

Comment: $$\frac{\frac ab}{\frac cd}=\frac{ad}{bc}$$
Here $$\frac{\frac{x-(x+h)}{2x(x+h)}}{\frac{h}{1}}$$

Comment: Although it's hard to tell, what's in the red both is of the form $(a/b)/c$, which in turn is equal to $a/(bc)$.

Comment: it is not $h$ that jumps from the bottom to the middle. It is the middle that falls at the bottom. Well, I just saw it already explained in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The author made no error. The author was merely using the property that
$$\frac{\frac{a}{b}}{c}=\frac{a}{bc}$$
I agree that the author's steps are hard to follow due to the fraction bars that look very similar. To clarify, though, inside of the red box, the author has
$$a=x-(x+h)$$
$$b=2x(x+h)$$
$$c=h$$
Or you could think of it this way - he multiplied the numerator and denominator both by $2x(x+h)$, which is the same as multiplying by $1$.

Answer (score 3):

If you have something of the form $$\frac{\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)}{h}$$ then this can be re-written as $$\frac{a}{b} \times \frac{1}{h} = \frac{a}{bh}.$$ This may be made more lucid to you by replacing $\frac{a}{b}$ with $c$. This is precisely your problem with $a=x-(x+h)$ and  $b = 2x(x+h)$.

Answer (score 1):

$\dfrac{\frac {x-(x+h)}{2x(x+h)}}{h} =$

$\frac {x-(x+h)}{2x(x+h)}\times \dfrac 1{h}=$

$\dfrac {x - x - h}{2xh(x+h)}$

Frankly, I would have done it this way:

$\dfrac {\frac 1{2(x+h)} - \frac 1{2x}}{h}=$

$\dfrac{[\frac 1{2(x+h)} - \frac 1{2x}]\times \frac 1h}{h\times \frac 1h}=$

$\dfrac 1{2h(x+h)} - \dfrac 1{2xh}=$

$\dfrac{x - (x+h)}{2xh(x+h)}$

But, as other answers and comments have stated;  these are both simply ways of expressing $\dfrac {\frac ab}{c} = \dfrac {a}{bc}$.  Which can be verified three ways:

i) $\dfrac {\frac ab}{c} =\dfrac {\frac ab\times b}{c\times b}= \dfrac {a}{bc}$

ii) $\dfrac {\frac ab}{c} =\dfrac {\frac ab\times \frac 1c}{c\times \frac 1c} =  \dfrac {a}{bc}$

iii)$\dfrac {\frac ab}{c} =\frac ab \times \dfrac {1}{c} =  \dfrac {a}{bc}$

oh, and I guess this fourth way is also legitimate:

iv)  $\dfrac {\frac ab}{c} = \dfrac {a \times\frac 1b}{c} = \frac ac \times \frac 1b = \dfrac a{bc}$.

.... of course, *visibly*, the problem is trying to recognize the difference between   $\frac {a+b+c}{\frac {d+e+f}{g+h+i}}$ and $\frac{\frac {a+b+c} {d+e+f}}{g+h+i}$.  It never hurts to throw in deambiguating parenthesis $\frac {a+b+c}{(\frac {d+e+f}{g+h+i})}\ne \frac{(\frac {a+b+c} {d+e+f})}{g+h+i}$